# Can't compile in Rust

Tags: ubuntu, rust, rust-cargo, rustup

I'm using ubuntu 20.04. 
rust version

```
 ❯ rustc --version --verbose
    rustc 1.71.0 (8ede3aae2 2023-07-12)
    binary: rustc
    commit-hash: 8ede3aae28fe6e4d52b38157d7bfe0d3bceef225
    commit-date: 2023-07-12
    host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    release: 1.71.0
    LLVM version: 16.0.5
```

file name **file.rs**

```
fn main(){
    println!("Hello World!");
}
```

when I run command `rustc file.rs`
there are error appear

```
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: LC_ALL="C" PATH="/home/ikrom/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin:/home/ikrom/.cargo/bin:/home/ikrom/command-central/CommandCentral/client/bin:/home/ikrom/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin:/home/ikrom/bin:/usr/bin/java/bin" VSLANG="1033" "cc" "-m64" "/tmp/rustcJQAL9c/symbols.o" "file.file.34d691a9eaaa1d91-cgu.0.rcgu.o" "file.file.34d691a9eaaa1d91-cgu.1.rcgu.o" "file.file.34d691a9eaaa1d91-cgu.2.rcgu.o" "file.file.34d691a9eaaa1d91-cgu.3.rcgu.o" "file.file.34d691a9eaaa1d91-cgu.4.rcgu.o" "file.file.34d691a9eaaa1d91-cgu.5.rcgu.o" "file.1hs7aqwua5pqej5m.rcgu.o" "-Wl,--as-needed" "-L" "/home/ikrom/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "/home/ikrom/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd-0d91c78a7710ed2e.rlib" "/home/ikrom/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libpanic_unwind-9bfeb974ba4dc4e7.rlib" "/home/ikrom/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libobject-7dd2d47ddb5fff81.rlib" "/home/ikrom/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libmemchr-18d5ce8e8a320b85.rlib" "/home/ikrom/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libaddr2line-69d2770595dc6161.rlib" "/home/ikrom/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libgimli-b156a020cc470e38.rlib" "/home/ikrom/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_demangle-84091f15e468b1ee.rlib" "/home/ikrom/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd_detect-fbde6acb28b510ca.rlib" "/home/ikrom/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libhashbrown-e9de5d8ee4e7a3dd.rlib" "/home/ikrom/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_alloc-9023252e4f119830.rlib" "/home/ikrom/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libminiz_oxide-fcbb01769e88af40.rlib" "/home/ikrom/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libadler-f69e84994e245fea.rlib" "/home/ikrom/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libunwind-27b55c02caca49ea.rlib" "/home/ikrom/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcfg_if-579b26075cbe9eca.rlib" "/home/ikrom/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liblibc-54c30397d4b33d3b.rlib" "/home/ikrom/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liballoc-65fb576691133eee.rlib" "/home/ikrom/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_core-3fff6412017c0b89.rlib" "/home/ikrom/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcore-fd3918c72578db43.rlib" "/home/ikrom/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcompiler_builtins-2a597573799b576f.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lgcc_s" "-lutil" "-lrt" "-lpthread" "-lm" "-ldl" "-lc" "-Wl,--eh-frame-hdr" "-Wl,-z,noexecstack" "-L" "/home/ikrom/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-o" "file" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-pie" "-Wl,-z,relro,-z,now" "-nodefaultlibs"
  = note: SEVERE: Invalid params.
          

error: aborting due to previous error
```

then after that, many file comes with prefix **file.random.rcgu.o**
[image: click this images to see the file name]

anyone please help me

I was trying to uninstall and install again rust but same.
method I was try to install rust is
`sudo apt install rustc`
and also install using this command
`curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh`

**Hello everyone I have been found the solution**
look this https://users.rust-lang.org/t/cant-compile-in-rust/97000/11

Comment: Do you have `build-essential` installed? Try `sudo apt install build-essential`

Comment: Yes, I have build-essential

Comment: **Do not use `rustc` directly**. Always use `cargo`. This is not the source of your problem, though.

Comment: hi @ChayimFriedman I have been following those step https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/getting-started/first-steps.html but the result it's same, error.

Comment: What do you get when you run `cc --version` in terminal?

Comment: I'm pretty confident you have something called `cc` in your path that is *not* what Rust is expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Rust requires CC for linking.

Install `build-essential` package to install common tools required for dev

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

Or you can also opt in to install only CC with

```bash
sudo apt install gcc
```

I would recommend the installing `build-essential`

** **IMPORTANT**
Once installed don't forget to

```
cargo clean
```

As in some cases I have some corruptions in target dir preventing subsequent cargo run

Now you should be good with

```bash
cargo run
```

OUTPUT:

```
     Running `target/debug/hello`
Hello, world!
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer,
anyway maybe 3 month ago I has been able to install and learning rust and those all it's able and no error when I compiling rust file.

I was try your Idea but same thing happen, still error